# Removing grid lines in a map and smoothing in maps

Tags: dictionary, matplotlib, mapping, gridding

I am trying to remove the grids on my map. I used several commands for example: plt.grid(), plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = False but nothing happens, the map produced as is with the grids. Is there any possible way to remove the grids?
Another thing also, how can I make my plot to be smoothed instead of having the data as blocks (see below a sample of the plot).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwRLC.png)
Please assist in this regard.

Truly appreciate your time.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [reprex] that creates this map.

Comment: Does `ax.grid(False)` work?

Comment: The weird thing with python sometimes commands wouldn't work; I am trying to set the font type of the tick of the color bar using this line of codes: for tick in cbar.ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label2.set_fontweight('bold') . It is not working. Any idea?